# How to simultaneously diagonalize two commuting matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I'm working on a numerical problem involving simultaneous diagonalization.

I have two matrices, $K$ and $B$, for which $[K,B]=0$. I want to use the eigenvectors of $B$ to diagonalize $K$. Here is the $B$ matrix,

\begin{equation}
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

$B$ is singular, is it still possible to use it to diagonalize $K$? First I get the eigenvectors of $B$, which MATLAB will return in a matrix $V$ with the $B$ eigenvectors as it's columns. Then
I use this matrix $V$ to block diagonalize $K$, i.e.

\begin{align}
V^{-1}KV = [K]_{BD}
\end{align}

$[K]_{BD}$ denotes that $K$ is in the basis where it is now block diagonal. Then I can diagonalize each of $[K]_{BD}$'s blocks, getting eigenvectors of those blocks. Padding those block-eigenvectors with zeros should give me the eigenvectors of the full $[K]_{BD}$. I assemble  these into a matrix, let's call it $S$. Then I can diagonalize $S$ by performing,

\begin{align}
S^{-1}[K]_{BD}S = K_D 
\end{align}

where $K_D$ is the now diagonal $K$. I can apply

\begin{align}
S^{-1}(V^{-1}BV)S = B_D
\end{align}

and I will have simultaneously diagonalized the $K$ and $B$ matrix as desired.

Some issues I'm facing / questions I have are:

1. MATLAB tends to return the matrix of eigenvectors (the $V$ or the $S$) with an arbitrary ordering of the columns (it's at the whims of algorithmic efficiency). Does this matter for my procedure? I think this is a problem because the procedure relies on a correspondence between the degenerate subspaces of $B$ and the blocks of $[K]_{BD}$.
2. As mentioned, is $B$ being singular a problem? It seems like it is because MATLAB is throwing an error when I try to use $V^{-1}$ in the computation.
3. My understanding of this whole topic isn't great. I'm trying to follow the procedure shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qtVSg66lHE&ab_channel=LorenzoSadun). But maybe someone that reads this post can direct me to a good textbook section to clear up any misconceptions you notice in the above.

Comment: The order of columns matters, you want columns with the same eigenvalue go next to each other to get a block-diagonal matrix. But other than the that whatever the order is in $V$ or $S$ would just determine in what order the eigenvalues appear in your $K_D$, you seem to be synchronizing the order of blocks when you assemble $S$. Being singular just means having a 0 eigenvalue, it makes no difference in diagonalization. It is possible that $V$ is close to being singular, but that would have to do with eigenvectors being close to being dependent, not with singularity of $B$.

Comment: Another possibility is that $B$ isn't diagonalizable (is it symmetric?). I am not sure what the MATLAB command you are using would do for $V$ in that case. Perhaps produce a degenerate matrix or return error.

Comment: There wouldn't be a problem just because $B$ is singular. If $B$ fails to be diagonalizable, then the $V$ that returns is singular, which is probably the source of your issues. You could try using the Jordan form of $B$ instead

Comment: Regarding the ordering of eigenvalues: if `D` is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, you can always extract the eigenvectors associated with a specific eigenvalue `k` as the columns of `V(:,diag(D)==k)`

Comment: @BenGrossmann the returned $V$ does indeed appear to be singular. I tried using the Jordan form of $B$ instead, and the $V$ (I'll refer to it as $V_j$) returned by that function is invertible. I don't understand this. Does this just come down to the fact that $V_j$ has a different ordering of the columns, i.e. the eigenvectors of $B$? Or does the scaling that is used to produce $V_j$ also matter?

Comment: @AdamTrask No, that's not it. The point is that $B$ is not diagonalizable, which is to say that there are not enough eigenvectors of $B$ to build an invertible matrix. Note that $V_j$ uses both eigenvectors and [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) to produce an invertible matrix.

Comment: @AdamTrask That said, this is all very strange given that your matrix is skew-symmetric. If $B$ is skew-symmetric, then it should follow that $B$ is diagonalizable with imaginary eigenvalues.